# Spanish characters in R Markdown are working in headers but not the body, even though it does work in pure Latex

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

R Markdown is working properly on the headers of my document, but not the body, as spanish characters look different. When I use pure Latex (Overleaf) it works in both the body and header.

If I copy-paste spanish characters (eg. `á, é, ñ, ó`) they are preserved as such, but if I use the backslash-hyphen method (`\'a, \'e, \~n, \'o`) they only translate properly in the headers of the document but not the body.

I already checked if i was using `utf8` (I was), and the `headers-include` and `\usepackage` functions didn't help either.

```
\section{Secci\'on \~n}
Hola, esta es mi primera edici\'on de texto
\subsection{Subsecci\'on}
Esto deber\'ia ser una subsecci\'on.
Ahora, anotaré una f\'ormula, tal que $\lim_{x \rightarrow y} x = y$
```

This is how it currently knits:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P91QF.png]

As you can see, the headers display said characters properly, while the body only renders spanish characters correctly if It type them directly (the e), which I can't do because my keyboard doesn't have them. Using unicode is a not an ideal solution.

Comment: seems like someone raised this issue back in 2018.
https://community.rstudio.com/t/problem-rendering-foreign-languages-in-rmd/17931/7
however from what I can see, it is still open without a resolution.
https://github.com/r-lib/evaluate/issues/59

Comment: You are right. It is a problem with knitr and it is currently too expensive/radical to change. The best solution seems to be to adapt to a new keyboard (from QWERTY to US international), as it supports said characters if encoding is in UTF-8.

Comment: Can you please share the intermediate .tex file?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use such native TeX commands as `\'` to add characters with accents to your document if you set `xelatex` as the `latex_engine`.

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Author"
date: "2020/4/16"
output:
  pdf_document2:
  #bookdown::pdf_document2: #When you need cross-referencing of figures and tabular
    latex_engine: xelatex
---

# Sección ñ

Hola, esta es mi primera edición de texto

## Subsección

Esto debería ser una subsección.
Ahora, anotaré una fórmula, tal que $\lim_{x \rightarrow y} x = y$
```